# Does AppFabric Caching Support Persistance for WCF Durable Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, appfabric

We have Durable Service which is configured to use SqlPersistenceProvider. For each and every call to the WCF Durable service is taking around 3 to 4 seconds totally out of which, just 200 ms is actual processing time. rest of the timing are solely used for Serizlization (its big object) or Saving the big object to sqlserver.

Anyone, Please guide me to set up AppFabric caching 1.1 to use instead of default sqlpersistenceprovider?

Is this supported by AppFabric ? I am very new to AppFabric.

Attached is the trace screenshot showing the processing time  200 ms 
SQL Server saving , Loading time is 3,2 seconds respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppFabric and any other distributed cache will not solve the serialization issue. Object has to be serialized to be stored outside of your process.

Consider other design options if serialization of big objects is the biggest time consumer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer How to identify whether Serialization or SQL server is taking more time ? is that possible to identify from screenshot.

Comment: I would use SQL profiling with Tuning template to measure timing for SQL server queries.